# Saving csv from android. File is Untitled while sharing

Tags: java, android, csv, android-intent, export

I am developing an application in android studio using java that reads in a csv file and eventually exports a that file back out. The outputted csv file is being named `Untitled.csv`, however I would like it to maintain the original filename that it was read into the program in. Is there a way to do this? Please see my code below:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse(mypath);
Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
fileIntent.setType("text/csv");
fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Data");
fileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Send data"));
```

where 'mypath' is '0/emulated/android/data/some_folder/backup_file_20191217.csv'

UPDATE 20-Dec-2019: I just noticed that from some devices, the file is named correctly with actual filename, but from some devices, it is exported as Untitled. I have no idea why is this happening. 
If someone knows anything about this, I request you to please help me out.

UPDATE 22-Dec-2019: When I share with other applications, I get the filename correctly, but when I share using whatsapp, the filename is Untitled. Now, the problem is with my code? or whatsapp?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `ACTION_SENDTO` instead. This allows you to provide an actual file URI which is likely interpreted as a file and not a binary stream (which should preserve the filename):

```
Uri path = Uri.parse(mypath);
Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
fileIntent.setData(path);
fileIntent.setType("text/csv");
fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Data");
fileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Send data"));
```

Actually, it might also work with your existing code (using `ACTION_SEND`) if you just add the `fileIntent.setData()` line **before** the `fileIntent.setType()` line. This all depends on the behaviour of the App that is doing the sharing (ie: not your App).

Comment: It does not work. Even the tool is suggesting that adding setData before setType may lead to data loss when I do this.

Comment: Did you try with `ACTION_SENDTO`?

Comment: You can, of course, just add `setData()` and remove `setType()` which should cause the type to be set based on the file extension. Or you can use `setDataAndType()` and pass both parameters in the same call.

Comment: SENDTO is opening a new activity (to send an email), without attaching the file.

Comment: Also, when I comment out setType("text/csv") and add only setData(path), it is showing error: setData(android.net.Uri) in Intent cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: UPDATE 20-Dec-2019: I just noticed that from some devices, the file is named correctly with actual filename, but from some devices, it is exported as Untitled. I have no idea why is this happening. If someone knows anything about this, I request you to please help me out.

Comment: When you call `setData(path)` the parameter `path` needs to be a `Uri`, not a `String`. In the code I showed you in my answer, `path` is  a `Uri`.

Comment: When you share, another App is executing. Depending on which other App that is, the passed data (`Intent` extras, etc) are used differently. This is why you get different results on different devices.

Comment: When I used SENDTO, it opens a new sharing activity and toast says cannot attach file.

Comment: I am very confused here. In the code that I posted in question, we are clearly passing file path, but why is file name becoming as untitled when sharing.

Comment: everything is going correctly, the data inside the file is also as expected, but only the file name is untitled. I really wonder why

Comment: UPDATE 22-Dec-2019: When I share with other applications, I get the filename correctly, but when I share using whatsapp, the filename is Untitled. Now, the problem is with my code? or whatsapp?

Comment: There is no "problem". It is just a lack of agreement. Unfortunately these behaviours are not well documented, nor standardized. Nowhere does it say what the target application should do with the passed parameters. You might need to ask this question on a Whatsapp developer forum to get a better answer.